# Is $\langle\chi,\lambda\rangle=0$, whenever the limit exists? Where is the mistake?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory, quivers

Suppose $G$ is a linearly reductive algebraic group acting linearly on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$. This induces an action on the coordinate ring $\mathbb{C}[V]$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_on_coordinate_rings)). Let $\chi:G\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^*$ be a multiplicative character of $G$. An element $f\in\mathbb{C}[V]$ is said to be relative invariant of weight $\chi$ if $$(g\cdot f)(x):=f(g^{-1}\cdot x)=\chi(g)f(x),\text{ for every }x\in V\text{ and }g\in G.$$ (You can also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-invariant_of_a_quiver))

Suppose $a\in V$ is a $\chi$-semi-stable point. Hence, by definition, there exists a relative invariant, say $p\in\mathbb{C}[V]$, of weight $\chi^n$, for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, (see the full definition below)

[image]

Suppose there exists a one-parameter subgroup $\lambda$ of $G$ such the limit $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\lambda(t)\cdot a$ exists. Let $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\lambda(t)\cdot a=b$. By the proposition below

[image]

We know that $\chi(\lambda(t))=t^{m}$, for some non-negative integer $m$. Since $\chi$ is a multiplicative character, $\chi(\lambda(t)^{-1})=t^{-m}$.

Since $p$ is a polynomial, it's a continuous function. Therefore, $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}t^{-nm}p(a)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\chi^n(\lambda(t)^{-1})p(a)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}p(\lambda(t)\cdot a)=p(\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\lambda(t)\cdot a)=p(b)$$ But if $m>0$ then the left hand side diverges. Therefore, $m=0$.

What I'm confused about is that this would mean $\langle\chi,\lambda\rangle$ is always $0$, but I don't think this is true. I don't understand where the mistake is.

The reference for above definition and proposition is- A. D. King [Moduli of representations of finite dimensional algebras](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Esek/sem/stability/king.pdf)

Comment: King's definition of relative invariant (in the second paragraph of Section 2) has the opposite sign convention to the one you state.

Comment: @TerryTao thanks a lot for your reply. So, according to my sign convention, should the proposition be "... satisfies $\langle\chi,\lambda\rangle\leq 0$"

Comment: Sure, though if your objective is to read through King's paper, I would recommend using King's sign conventions rather than the sign conventions from a Wikipedia article.